# Deploying a Vite Typescript+React app to Apache server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, apache, vite

I am using XAMPP Apache server on a local machine for testing,

I am able to follow this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lATafp15HWA and run the app with `npm run dev` however, I cannot seem to be able to deploy it to run on a local server.

I tried to follow the directions here:
https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html

By running the `npx vite build` command

I can see a `dist` folder created that has `index.html` assets, JS code, and CSS

If I copy this folder to `C:\XAMPP\htdocs\temp` , however, I get a blank page when I go to
`http://localhost/temp/index.html` in the **same** browser. But I can see the title of the webpage is displayed in the title bar

I can confirm the server is running, because `http://localhost/` returns the XAMPP welcome page.

Am I missing some steps in building or hosting this website? Do I need to enable something in XAMPP?

I have tested that `npx vite serve` also works and the web page is displayed,

I also tried with `live-server` and it works as well,

The app is structured below:

```
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom"
import { Container } from 'react-bootstrap'
import { Home } from "./pages/Home";
import { Store } from "./pages/Store";
import { About } from "./pages/About";
import { Navbar } from "./components/Navbar"
import { ShoppingCartProvider } from "./context/ShoppingCartContext";

function App() {
  return (
    <ShoppingCartProvider>
      <Navbar />
      <Container className="mb-4">
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/store" element={<Store />} />
          <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
        </Routes>
      </Container>
    </ShoppingCartProvider>
  )
}

export default App
```

Comment: have you resolved this? i have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

```
    // vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'

export default defineConfig({
  base: './',
});
```

I have modified one response of stackoverflow helped me. You need add base with relative path.